# How to make a variable array based on information inside of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a list of sheets to hide or unhide based on whether a checkbox is clicked. I want to have a list of the sheets over a range of cells, but my function isn't working. I assume it's because it is considered a string and I am calling it as something.

```
With Worksheets("Home Page").Cells
    Set findSheets = .Find(What:="Sheets", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

findSheets.Select
Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
num = 1

ArrayList = Chr(34) & Selection.Value & Chr(34)
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

For Each MyCell In Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    ArrayList = ArrayList & ", " & Chr(34) & Selection.Value & Chr(34)
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
ArrayList = ArrayList & ")"
ArrayList = Array(ArrayList)

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Worksheets(Array(ArrayList)).Visible = True
Else
    Worksheets(Array(ArrayList)).Visible = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim shet
For Each shet In arraylist
    Worksheets(shet).Visible = CheckBox1.Value
Next shet
```